# Reading JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse some json that my server replies me.
I am getting this answer from the server:

```
{
"ROWCOUNT": 1,
"COLUMNS": [
    "REGISTRATION_DT",
    "USERNAME",
    "PASSWORD",
    "FNAME",
    "LNAME",
    "EMAIL",
    "MOBILE",
    "FACEBOOK_ID"
],
"DATA": {
    "REGISTRATION_DT": [
        "March, 17 2012 16:18:00"
    ],
    "USERNAME": [
        "user"
    ],
    "PASSWORD": [
        pass
    ],
    "FNAME": [
        "name"
    ],
    "LNAME": [
        "lname"
    ],
    "EMAIL": [
        "somemail"
    ],
    "MOBILE": [
        mobile
    ],
    "FACEBOOK_ID": [
        "fbid"
    ]
}
```

}

I am trying to extract the data with this way:

```
var xml2 = this.responseData;
var xml3 = JSON.parse(xml2); 
Ti.API.log(xml3.DATA[0].FNAME);
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You're reading your JSON wrong. `DATA` is an object of arrays and not vica versa.

```
Ti.API.log( xml3.DATA.FNAME[0] );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ti.API.log(xml3.DATA.FNAME[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two fields come without quotes:

```
"PASSWORD": [
    pass
]
```

And

```
"MOBILE": [
    mobile
],
```

Answer (score 0):

`xml3.DATA` is an object, not an array.

You need to write

```
xml3.DATA.FNAME[0]
```